# want to send data from one table to another on button click

Tags: c#-4.0

In the below code i used label and text box to send data to sql . but instead of using label and textbox i want to send data  from one table to another on button click . please let me know the shortest path .

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            con1.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update coupon set status =('" + Label2.Text + "'),macaddress =('" + mac.Text + "') where accode =('" + usename.Text + "')", con1);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con1.Close();

            AddNewUserToNomadix();
```

Comment: Please write all code you have and how you try to solve the problem